# Zip a complete directory in Perl

Tags: perl

I have tried zipping a directory which contains sub directories and files in perl and this is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

use List::Util qw(first);

use Archive::Zip qw(:ERROR_CODES :CONSTANTS);

my $input= 'D:\temp\sample';

my $outDir = 'D:\out\sample.zip';

my $obj = Archive::Zip->new();

$obj->addTree( $input );

# # Write the files to zip.
if ($obj->writeToFileNamed($outDir) == AZ_OK) 
{  
    # write to disk
    print "\n\nArchive created successfully!\n";
} 
else 
{
    print "Error while Zipping !";
}
```

When i execute this, the zip file ( sample.zip ) is created.

Always the unzipping is done manually selecting the option " Extract Here ".

When i unzip this , the directory bursts open putting all the subfolders and files at the same location( D:\out).

What i want is, i expect the output to be a unique folder ( D:\out\sample)

So, what changes need to be done in my code. Pls help me.

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive::Zip#Zip-Archive-Tree-operations):

> **$zip->addTree( $root, $dest [, $pred, $compressionLevel ] ) -- Add tree of files to a zip**
>
> `$root` is the root of the tree of files and directories to be added. It
>   is a valid directory name on your system. `$dest` is the name for the
>   root in the zip file (undef or blank means to use relative pathnames).
>   It is a valid ZIP directory name (that is, it uses forward slashes (/)
>   for separating directory components).

And the examples, also from the docs:

```
use Archive::Zip;
my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();

# add all readable files and directories below . as xyz/*
$zip->addTree( '.', 'xyz' );

# add all readable plain files below /abc as def/*
$zip->addTree( '/abc', 'def', sub { -f && -r } );

# add all .c files below /tmp as stuff/*
$zip->addTreeMatching( '/tmp', 'stuff', '\.c$' );

# add all .o files below /tmp as stuff/* if they aren't writable
$zip->addTreeMatching( '/tmp', 'stuff', '\.o$', sub { ! -w } );

# add all .so files below /tmp that are smaller than 200 bytes as stuff/*
$zip->addTreeMatching( '/tmp', 'stuff', '\.o$', sub { -s < 200 } );

# and write them into a file
$zip->writeToFileNamed('xxx.zip');

# now extract the same files into /tmpx
$zip->extractTree( 'stuff', '/tmpx' );
```